# British Citizenship of HKSAR resident

Tags: united-kingdom, citizenship, hong-kong

Okay, so here's a pretty complex case (kudos to those who would bother to read through the whole thing at all).
I was born in Hong Kong in September 1995 (still a British colony at the time) and my parents (at the time of my birth) are NOT British citizens yet.

However, through the British Nationality (Hong Kong) Act 1990 my parents both became British Citizens (since my father is of Indian descent) in December 1995. My parents claimed that they have applied on my behalf (as I was still an infant) but they actually forgot to collect the certificate from the British embassy. This leaves a large question mark concerning on whether my application 20 years ago is successful at all and I am unsure how I should proceed. Any suggestions on what to do next?

Comment: Have you tried contacting the UK consulate?

Comment: Yes I did but they didn't offer much advice apart from asking me to apply again / notify the Home Office through e-mail

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way forward would be to make a formal representation to the deciding post, where your parents had applied for your British registration certificate.

If the decision was to grant you British nationality was approved, then it should not be an issue, as you would be able to receive your certificate from them.